# Нахождение субстрок и возврат определенного значения VBA makro

Tags: excel, vba

Есть список в столбце D, нужно чтобы макрос находил субстроки в этом списке и возвращал определенные значения в столбец E. Цикл я написал и функцию нахождения субстроки тоже нашел, но она работает не совсем правильно. То есть работает, но если я правильно понимаю, по принципе нахождения первой буквы.

Пример кода:

```
Sub Search()

Dim i As Long
Dim case1, case2, case3, case4, case5, case6, case7, case8 As String

case1 = "NOT BANK RESIDENTIAL"
case2 = "BANK RESIDENTIAL"
case3 = "NOT BANK RESIDENTIAL Spot FX"
case4 = "BANK RESIDENTIAL Spot FX"
case5 = "NOT BANK NON-RESIDENTIAL"
case6 = "BANK NON-RESIDENTIAL"
case7 = "NOT BANK NON-RESIDENTIAL Spot FX"
case8 = "BANK NON-RESIDENTIAL Spot FX"
    For i = 1 To CInt(Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row) + 1

         If InStr(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4), case1) <> 0 Then
       Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5) = "7901"

       ElseIf InStr(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4), case2) <> 0 Then
       Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5) = "7501"

       ElseIf InStr(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4), case3) <> 0 Then
       Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5) = "7901"

       ElseIf InStr(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4), case4) <> 0 Then
       Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5) = "7503"

       ElseIf InStr(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4), case5) <> 0 Then
       Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5) = "7901"

       ElseIf InStr(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4), case6) <> 0 Then
       Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5) = "7501"

       ElseIf InStr(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4), case7) <> 0 Then
       Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5) = "7901"

       ElseIf InStr(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4), case8) <> 0 Then
       Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5) = "7530"

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема по моему в неправильной последовательности `If`: например, Вы никогда не получите значение 7503 по той простой причине, что строка `case4` содержит в себе `case2`, по этому если текст ячейки содержит `"BANK RESIDENTIAL Spot FX"`, он содержит также и `"BANK RESIDENTIAL"` и в ответ получите `7501` а не `7503`.

Comment: поставил в условии case8 i case4 раньше чем 6 и 2 и вроде все стало работать правильно. а я то все это время думал что проблема в том что оно ищет только лишь по первой букве. но так вроде бы работает правильно. спасибо большое!

Comment: @Vlad Stepanov, Если помогло, Вам следует отметить ответ  *koshe* как правильный

Answer (score 0):

О главной ошибке написано в ответе *@koshe* - субстроки нужно проверять в порядке убывания длины текста.

Ниже - о менее существенных ошибках и оптимизации кода.

В Вашем варинте при инициализации переменных только *case8 As String*, тип других - *Variant*. В *VBA* нужно указывать тип для каждой переменной. Этим оптимизируется использование оперативной памяти.

Родителя поместить под оператор *With*. Обращение к объекту (в данном случае - листу) будет только один раз, при инициализации.

```
With Sheets(1)
    For i = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        If InStr(.Cells(i, 4), case1) <> 0 Then
            .Cells(i, 5) = "7901"
        ..........................
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Работа с объектами листа медленная. Данные с листа помещаем в массив, обрабатываем в памяти и выгружаем на лист - только два обращения к ячейкам. Субстроки тоже помещаем в массив (*субстроки/значения* можно взять из ячеек, предварительно разместив таблицу на листе).

```
Sub Search()
Dim aData(), aStr()
Dim lRwD As Long, lRwStr As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
    lRwStr = 8 ' к-во субстрок
    ReDim aStr(1 To lRwStr, 1 To 2) ' задаем размерность массива'
    ' заносим субстроки и их значения в массив'
    aStr(1, 1) = "NOT BANK NON-RESIDENTIAL Spot FX":    aStr(1, 2) = 7901
    aStr(2, 1) = "NOT BANK RESIDENTIAL Spot FX":        aStr(2, 2) = 7901
    aStr(3, 1) = "NOT BANK NON-RESIDENTIAL":            aStr(3, 2) = 7901
    aStr(4, 1) = "NOT BANK RESIDENTIAL":                aStr(4, 2) = 7901
    aStr(5, 1) = "BANK NON-RESIDENTIAL Spot FX":        aStr(5, 2) = 7530
    aStr(6, 1) = "BANK RESIDENTIAL Spot FX":            aStr(6, 2) = 7503
    aStr(7, 1) = "BANK NON-RESIDENTIAL":                aStr(7, 2) = 7501
    aStr(8, 1) = "BANK RESIDENTIAL":                    aStr(8, 2) = 7501

    With Sheets(1)
        lRwD = .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row ' последняя заполненная видимая строка'
        aData = .Range("D1:D" & lRwD).Value ' данные столбца D в массив'
        ReDim Preserve aData(1 To lRwD, 1 To 2) ' добавлям столбец для результата'

        For i = 1 To lRwD ' цикл по данным'
            For j = 1 To lRwStr ' цикл по субстрокам'
                If InStr(aData(i, 1), aStr(j, 1)) <> 0 Then ' нашли вхождение субстроки'
                    aData(i, 2) = aStr(j, 2) ' записываем значение'
                    Exit For ' переходим к следующей записи в данных'
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

        .Range("D1").Resize(lRwD, 2).Value = aData ' выгружаем на лист'
    End With
End Sub
```